# how to route the traffic of android native applications to the proxy set manually in wi-fi

Tags: android, proxy

I set the proxy server ip in wifi of android 4.4 samasung note 2 device. Now my need is that the native application's traffic should route to this manually set proxy but I think it is not the case. Is there some other thing one has to do to make native application traffic to go to proxy server set in wifi. As I think this will work for browser but not native applications.

Comment: This question has nothing todo with programming.